# Express pass values in route to view with ejs

Tags: express, ejs

This is my post route:

```
// CRUD posts.
app.post('/crud', function(req, res) {
  db.users.addPost(req.body);
  res.redirect('crud')
});
```

This is my get route:

```
app.get('/crud', function(req, res) {
  res.render('crud', {
    user: req.user,
    posts: db.users.retrievePost()
  });
});
```

This is the function I use to retrieve posts from my database:

```
// Retrieve posts from database to pass to view.
exports.retrievePost = function() {
  var cursor = postsCollection.find().toArray(function(err, record) {
    console.log(record);
    return record;
  });
}
```

When I log record, it returns the following data:

```
[ 
  { _id: 57cb835ba8b8250bdcd65e5d, userCreate: 'This is a question' },
  { _id: 57cb85709435720c055b10e6, userCreate: 'hello' },
  { _id: 57cb87b10dc3ec0c3a78f970, userCreate: 'hello' },
  { _id: 57cb87c20dc3ec0c3a78f971, userCreate: 'what up here' } 
]
```

This is how I'm using ejs to display the userCreate values in my 'crud' view.

```
<ul class="posts">
  <% for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) { %>
  <li class="post">
    <span><%= posts[i].userCreate %></span>
  </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

**The error is:**
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Why would posts be undefined? In my get route when I rendered the view, I assigned the value of retrievePost() to posts. I then called on posts from that view that was rendered. We can assume that the function is exported properly because I use other functions from that same file in the same routes file. What is wrong here?

I would like to add to this post the fact that I tested passing

```
title : "testing"
```

and was able to render it in the following way:

```
<%= title %>
```

So I'm really not sure why posts won't work.

Comment: Because the value of `posts` passed to `res.render` is undefined. The `postsCollection.find()` will not have returned, and the value never passes back in any case. You need to have `retrievePost` also accept a callback (or do it with promises, etc).

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The anonymous function associated with cursor returns record, but retrievePost() does not. Is that what you are saying? If so I think you're right. Then, how would I have retrievePost() return that data instead of the anonymous function inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I described in my comment: The problem is the value of `posts` passed to `res.render` is undefined. The `postsCollection.find()` will not have returned, and the value never passes back in any case. You need to have `retrievePost` also accept a callback (or do it with promises, etc).

This is a very basic implementation of the needed behavior.

```
app.get('/crud', function(req, res) {
    // call passing in a callback
    db.users.retrievePost(function(err,result) {
        // call render inside this call back, after result has been retrieved
        res.render('crud', {user: req, user, posts: result});
    })
});

// Retrieve posts from database to pass to view.

exports.retrievePost = function(callback) {
   var cursor = postsCollection.find().toArray(function(err, record) {
      console.log(record);
      // naively just invokes the passed callback
      // you could also do error handling or other processing
      // here as well, before passing back the result through the callback
      callback(err,record);
   });
}
```

Comment: This worked. I'll have to study this functionality. I'm kind of confused about how data travels backwards from the exported function, into that functions parameter, and back to where the parameter came from.

Comment: @manbearpig1 It's functions all the way down. You're calling functions and passing in parameters which are functions. When the called function completes, it calls the function from the parameter (which invokes code you defined int he calling function). It's less confusing if you don't think too hard. :-)  Basically it is one of a number of strategies for dealing with asynchronicity. Callbacks are the oldest of the common methods for dealing with it, but I would also suggest you look into Promises, minimally of the JS variety, but probably with a library like Bluebird.

Answer (score -1):

It will be :

locals.posts.length()

rather than

posts.length